# An example of a primeless (i.e. module without prime submodule) and projective module

Tags: commutative-algebra

Please, give an example of a module $M$ such that $M$ is primeless (i.e. without prime submodule) and projective.
Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

I learn the notion of "prime module" from wiki's article [associated prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associated_prime). 
According to wiki,  it only needs to give a projective module which has no associated prime ideal.

Let $A=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]/(x_i^2\mid i=1,2,\ldots)$ which is a quotient ring of the infinitely many indeterminates polynomial ring over a field $k$. Then $A$ has only one prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}=(x_1,x_2,\ldots)$. It is not an associated prime, you cannot find an $f\in A$, such that $(0:f)=\mathfrak{m}$. And $A$ is a free module as $A$-module.

Comment: @m. sam. : You wrote: "Thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a module $M$ such that $M$ is not a free or a multiplication module and moreover $M$ is primeless and projective."  The proper place for such a comment is down here in the comments section.  I've deleted it from the answer.

Comment: Dear @Michael, you did well, of course, but how could  m. sam. with a reputation of only 23 edit this answer ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg : He did submit an edit, which I rejected.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Thanks for the explanation, @Michael.